# How to configure tsconfig.json for Chrome extension so I can create modules

Tags: typescript, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing some TypeScript in VS Code for a Chrome plugin. TS transpilation to JS works fine, but my primary .ts file is sufficiently large that I want to refactor some code into a separate module.

I created a file - common.ts - and moved some of my constants and functions over:

```
export function doSomething(foo : string): string { ... }
```

From my main .ts file, I can reference these exports by qualifying them, eg:

```
let result = common.doSomething("foo");
```

Currently, I am able to import this code with:

```
import common = require("./common");
```

VS Code has no problem with autocomplete or with building; however, when I open my extension, I get the error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: define is not defined at popup.ts:2

This is pointing to this part of the generated JavaScript:

```
define(["require", "exports", "./common"], function (require, exports, common) {
```

My tsconfig.json is currently:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es6",
        "module": "amd",
        "sourceMap": true
    }
}
```

I have tried using the "commonjs" module, but I've read that browsers don't support that. Even so, when I try it, I get a similar error with "exports" not being defined:

> Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });

I've also tried using the "system" module, but the same thing occurs with "System" not being defined:

> System.register(["./common"], function (exports_1, context_1) {

And finally with "es2015", which requires that I import instead as `import * as common from "./common";`. This line of code is reproduced exactly in the .js file, and Chrome gives me the error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token *

I've also changes the target around from es6 to various other targets, and I've tried importing instead as `import { doSomething } from "./common"`.

What's the appropriate way to configure tsconfig.json, to write the module (nb: I'm not using the `module` or `namespace` keywords in common.ts: it's just a series of export statements), and to import the module so that I can clean up this code and use it in a browser?

Answer (score 0):

Based on [some quick research](https://www.google.com/search?q=developing+google+chrome+extension+with+es6+modules) (I've never developed Chrome extensions myself), you'll need to either:

1. use a bundler such as Webpack that can translate one of the `"module"` output formats supported by TypeScript into a single JavaScript file, or
2. set `"module": "es2015"` and use an HTML page to load your modules into Chrome as described [here](https://medium.com/front-end-hacking/es6-modules-in-chrome-extensions-an-introduction-313b3fce955b) or [here](https://medium.com/@martinnovk_22870/using-javascript-es6-import-export-modules-in-chrome-extensions-f63a3a0d2736).